# why connection string is not found from my class library to another class library?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, connection-string, class-library

I am having the architecture like this :
 [image]

Where MVC layer is the presentation layer. EF is class library and Repository is another class library.I am trying to insert data to database from repository by creating the EF context object. Added EF reference into Repository class library. EF having the edmx file. its app.config having the connection string generated by EF.
code is :

```
public bool CreateUser(User _user)
   {
       context.Users.Add(_user);
       context.SaveChanges();
       return true;
   }
```

but while executing this I am getting following exception :

```
No connection string named 'MyEntitiesConnection' could be found in the application config file.
```

I tried to add same connection string with same name in repository app.config. but not working. anyone have solution ?

**Edited:**
connection string is :

```
<add name="MyEntitiesConnection" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EF.Entities.csdl|res://*/EF.Entities.ssdl|res://*/EF.Entities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=Servername\MSSQL2008R2;initial catalog=MyDBName;persist security info=True;user id=sa;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

app.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyEntitiesConnection" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EF.Entities.csdl|res://*/EF.Entities.ssdl|res://*/EF.Entities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=Servername\MSSQL2008R2;initial catalog=MyDBName;persist security info=True;user id=sa;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>    
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Show us the configuration.

Comment: Thanks, which configuration need to put here?

Comment: The configuration containing the connection string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any .NET application, only one config file is the natural starting point for looking for configuration information. For web applications, that's the `web.config` file at the root of the application<sup>1</sup>.

Whilst you may have a file called `app.config` in your repository project (and, indeed, some VS tooling may have added one) or your EF project, it's not *used* when you try to read configuration information.

The connection string section needs to exist in the web.config of your MVC app.

---

<sup>1</sup>For non-web applications, it's the `app.config` for the project that produces the `.exe` file and that gets automatically copied as `XXX.exe.config` during the build.

Comment: ok so does it means I cannot use EF in separate class library? since If we want to use EF as dll across the layers ?

Comment: You can use it in a separate class library. But you have to copy the connection string information into the `web.config` of the application that's *using* that class library. Class libraries don't get their own, separate `config` file.

Comment: That is what, I am using EF dll in Repository project. I tried to add same connection string in Repository's app.config. but same issue

Comment: I don't know how else to say this. Those `app.config` files in class library projects are meaningless. Only the `web.config` file matters.

Comment: but since Repository class library using context of EF class library, then It should use app.config setting of EF app.config configuration rather running context project.

Comment: **NO**. Again. Those `app.config` files that you have in your class library projects are meaningless. They are *not* used at all. Whenever you access config, no matter whether you're in the main application project or in a class library's code, the config file that is read is the config file for the application - the `web.config` for a web application or the `XXX.exe.config` file for any other type of application. Just put your connection information into the `web.config` file of your MVC application and you'll find that the error goes away.

Comment: worked for me to add connection string in web.config